# UPS Shipment JSON documentation

Tags: ups

Where can I find a guide for complete UPS Shipment JSON developer guide for shipment?

I know that they have a pdf guide for shipment, but I think not all fields are present on their JSON Developer pdf guide. Like the field `number of package` is missing. And is there a field where you can put the package value like `100 USD`.

And It's not well explained. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPS uses the same query structure everywhere.
The description of all fields is in the "Shipping Package Web Service Developer Guide.pdf". To use JSON, you just need to send a request to the URL specified in the "Shipping Package JSON Developer Guide.pdf".

Comment: can you give an example of the request you need to make?

Comment: if you download the archive from here https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit -> Shipping, you can find examples of requests and responses

Comment: Where can I find the "Shipping Package Web Service Developer Guide.pdf"?